# Sort file by different format of date field

Tags: shell, sorting, date

I am trying to sort a file by a date field. I realize this has been done before, however, I cannot find an example that has the following date format.

```
Canada Goose + 1x03 + For the Triumph of Evil + Sep/30/2013
Rucksack + 10x03 + Everybody's Crying Mercy + Oct/03/13
Test + 4x01 + Season 4, Episode 1 + Jun/01/14
New Family + 3x03 + Double Date + Oct/01/2013
```

I tried this command but it doesn't work

```
sort -t '+' -k 4.8,4.11 -k 4.4M -k 4.1,4.2 -b Test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a GNU awk installed, you may want to try this approach.

**sort.awk**

```
#!/bin/gawk -f
function convertToSeconds(date, fields) {
    split(date, fields, /\//)
    fields[1]=months[tolower(fields[1])]
    fields[2]=sprintf("%02d", fields[2])
    fields[3]=(length(fields[3]) == 2) ?  sprintf("2%03d", fields[3]) : fields[3]
    return mktime(sprintf("%s %s %s 00 00 00", fields[3], fields[1], fields[2]))
}
BEGIN {
    FS="( \\+ )"
    months["jan"]="01"; months["feb"]="02"; months["mar"]="03"; months["apr"]="04"
    months["may"]="05"; months["jun"]="06"; months["jul"]="07"; months["aug"]="08"
    months["sep"]="09"; months["oct"]="10"; months["nov"]="11"; months["dec"]="12"
}
{
    arr[convertToSeconds($4)]=$0
}
END {
    asorti(arr, dst)
    for(i=1; i<=FNR; ++i) {
        print arr[dst[i]]
    }
}
```

Give it an execute permission, then run it:

```bash
$ chmod +x ./sort.awk
$ ./sort.awk Test.txt
```

To save the changes into a new file, append this `>` operator.

```bash
$ ./sort.awk Test.txt > SortedTest.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

** UPDATE 1 **

revised sort key to explicitly list 4 digit year as prefix to circumvent year-end crossover issues

since OP only wants to ***sort date field***, the exact epochs mapping isn't needed at all ::

> ```
> mawk '$++NF = 366 * ( (_=($3) % 100) + 1900 + 100 * (_<50) ) \
>
>                  + int(_ * 10^8) + ($2) + (31) * \
>                    
> (index("  JANFEBMARAPRMAYJUNJULAUGSEPOCTNOVDEC", toupper($2)) / 3 - 1)'
> ```

```
23284 SEP 30 2013 201300737036
23285 OCT  1 2013 201300737038
23287 OCT  3 2013 201300737040
23541 JUN 14 2014 201400737293
```

1st column is original date generation order (the correct rank ordering), and the last column is the calculated sort index value - i tested every date from `jan 1st 1950` to `dec 31 2025`, and this simplistic approach ranks order just fine, even though it doesn't bother to calculate exact julian dates, or exact leap years,

**since the objective is merely finding a rank ordering method that yields the same sorting output as exact epoch seconds**

Answer (score 0):

You're nearly there. Use `sed`, for example, to add the missing centuries
then the `M` option of the 2nd `KEYDEF` field works with GNU `sort`:

```sh
sed 's:/\([0-9][0-9]\)$:/20\1:' << 'HERE' |
f1 + f2 + f3 + NoV/30/15
f1 + f2 + f3 + Sep/30/2013
f1 + f2 + f3 + Oct/03/13
f1 + f2 + f3 + Jun/01/14
f1 + f2 + f3 + Oct/01/2013
f1 + f2 + f3 + mAr/11/11
f1 + f2 + f3 + oct/03/2013
f1 + f2 + f3 + juL/17/1998
HERE
LC_ALL=C sort -t '+' -k 4.9 -k 4.2M,4.4 -k 4.6,4.7
```

Output:

```
f1 + f2 + f3 + juL/17/1998
f1 + f2 + f3 + mAr/11/2011
f1 + f2 + f3 + Sep/30/2013
f1 + f2 + f3 + Oct/01/2013
f1 + f2 + f3 + Oct/03/2013
f1 + f2 + f3 + oct/03/2013
f1 + f2 + f3 + Jun/01/2014
f1 + f2 + f3 + NoV/30/2015
```